# Can't retrieve userclaims after successful authentication with OIDC protocol

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement authentication with OIDC, and I'm using Microsoft's OIDC library to do so. The authentication process is working as expected. I get redirected to the idp, I signin and finally get redirected back to my client web app. I can see in the OIDC middleware that the claims from the authentication is retrieved succesfully and cookies have been created. However, if I try to retrieve the userclaims, by sending a GET request from my client web app to the authentication API, the user identity is not set properly and there are no claims. The thing that confuses me is the fact that calling the API resource directly from a browser with the cookies available retrieves the identity and claims as expected. It's as if the OIDC middleware doesn't trigger when requesting the claims through a client app, but it gets triggered when calling the resource directly.

Below I've added a sequencediagram to help understand the authentication flow. The responsibility of the "proxy" is to return the desired resource location, based on which authentication protocol is used. It doesn't communicate with the OIDC API in anyway and can therfore be ignored for the sake of clarity.

I'm unsure what the problem is and the amount of research and debugging hasn't really led anywhere. Is the problem due to the client not decoding the cookies? I've been assuming that everything authentication related is handled by the API, is that assumption wrong?

I'll gladly admit that I'm not well versed in the authentication domain, so there is a possibility that I'm misunderstanding something about the protocol.

Feel free to tell me if you're in need of more code smaples and further description of the problem at hand :)

Thanks in advance!

[image: Authentication flow]

Firstly I've searched around on the internet for around a week. Most people with similar questions had issues with their cookies, yet their solutions didn't work in my case.

I've played around with CORS and cookie policies, to ensure that there aren't any restrictions in that area that could affect the request.

Furthermore I've tried to create multiple simplified client applications in .NET framework 4.7.2 and .NET 6, in case the issue had something to do with the versions.

Lastly, here is the code in question:

**OIDC API Middleware:**

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ISecretSettings, SecretSettings>();
            ConfigureOIDCAuthentication(builder);
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => { builder.AllowAnyHeader();
builder.AllowAnyMethod();
builder.AllowAnyOrigin(); }));
         
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsStaging())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
                //Setup Secret.Json usage for development
                builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddUserSecrets<ISecretSettings>()
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables("Secrets:");
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }

        private static void ConfigureOIDCAuthentication(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OIDC")["authority"];
                options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("OIDC")["client_id"];
                options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Secrets")["ClientSecret"];
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost;
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");//request refresh token
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.UsePkce = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://broker.unilogin.dk/auth/realms/broker";
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnUserInformationReceived = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Claims from the ID token");
                    var claims = context.Principal?.Claims.ToList();

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
               
                OnTokenResponseReceived = tok => // Access token: SessionState, Code, ...
                {
                    //here's your token
                    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(tok.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);
                    var claims = token.Claims.ToList();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                
                OnMessageReceived = msg =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.ProtocolMessage.Code);
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.ProtocolMessage.SessionState);
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.ProtocolMessage.State);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            });

        }
    }
```

**OIDC API Authcontroller:**

```cs
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class AuthController : ControllerBase
  {
      private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;

      public AuthController(ILogger<AuthController> logger)
      {
          _logger = logger;
      }

      [HttpGet("/SignIn")]
      public ActionResult RedirectToUnilogin(string returnUrl = "/")
      {
          _logger.LogInformation("Redirecting to unilogin");
          return new ChallengeResult("OpenIdConnect", new AuthenticationProperties()
          {
              RedirectUri = returnUrl
          });
      }


      [HttpGet("/GetUser")]

      public ActionResult GetUser()
      {
          if (User.Identity != null)
          {
              if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
              {
                  var claims = ((ClaimsIdentity) this.User.Identity).Claims.Select(claim =>
                                  new { type = claim.Type, value = claim.Value })
                                  .ToArray();

                  return new JsonResult(new { isAuthenticated = true, claims });
              }
          }

          return new JsonResult(new { isAuthenticated = false });
      }
```

**Client application:**

```vb
Partial Class UniLoginOIDC
    Inherits Page
    Public Property ProxyURL As String
    Public Property ProxyGetUser As String
    Public Property ProxySignIn As String

    ' Helper method to parse claims from a JSON string (customize as per your JSON structure)

    Protected Async Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ProxyURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("proxyURL")
        ProxyGetUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("proxyGetUser")
        ProxySignIn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("proxySignIn")


        Using client As New HttpClient()
            'Get URL for userclaims
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync(ProxyURL + ProxyGetUser, Nothing)
            Dim userClaimURL As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            Dim claimResponse As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(userClaimURL)
            Dim claims As String = Await claimResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using
        If Not User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Await SendAuthRequest()
        Else
            Response.Redirect("/Charts")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Async Function SendAuthRequest() As Task
        ' Test object to test request data
        Dim responseDict = New With {.application = "ETU", .loginType = "unilogin", .returnUrl = "https://localhost:44326/TristTest.aspx"}
        Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseDict)

        Using client As New HttpClient()
            ' Convert the JSON string to a ByteArrayContent
            Dim content As New ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))

            ' Set the Content-Type header for form data
            content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")

            ' Make the POST request
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync(ProxyURL + ProxySignIn, content)

            ' Check if the request was successful
            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim responseContent As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                Console.WriteLine("Response Content: " & responseContent)
                Page.Response.Redirect(responseContent, False)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Request failed with status code: " & response.StatusCode)
            End If

        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

**Additional info:**

The API and Proxy are written in .NET 6, while the client application is written in .NET Framework 4.7.2